# Magento website ignores tax rates in checkout and doesn't remove tax from product price for some countries?

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I have been given a Magento website to fix. Essentially the company who has the website must display their prices with VAT/TAX of 20% on the site, and if the customer selects the United States the tax should be removed from the price of the products. The tax only really applies to the UK and the EU. The website has a tax rates list that specifies 20% tax for the UK and other EU countries that they have to charge tax to. There is a second rates list that specifies that Guernsey, Jersey and United States have a tax rate of 0.0. As well as this, the product prices are entered on to the system so that they are marked as including the tax. So when a customer selects United States, Guernsey or Jersey, the tax rate should be removed from the price of the product.

When the customer gets to the checkout and changes the country that the products are going to be shipped to, it seems that Magento doesn't seem to do this though. The price remains the same, even though the tax rates exist on the system for this to happen. I've gone through the settings all day, checked that the default country is set to the UK, that the products are set as Taxable Goods, that the tax should be calculated on the shipping address, but it just point blank refuses to remove the tax for these 3 countries.

What can I do?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Comment: I've exactly the same issue, how did you resolved this? thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Check also **Shipping origing** settings under:

**System->Configuration->Sales->Shipping settings->Origin**. It should be set to the country where the webshop is established.

Also double check: **Sales->Tax->Manage tax zones and rates**. Here you set the actual tax procents.

Comment: I've just gone on to look for Shipping Settings and I don't see it referenced where you say it is? Also I've checked the Manage Tax Zones and Rates section and the rates are all set correctly for the countries that should have a rate of 0.